# Argument to ggplot in own package

Tags: r, ggplot2

These lines works fine when in a function in an R-script:

```
hline_DL <- 22
p <- p + geom_hline(aes(yintercept=hline_DL), color="red", linetype=2)
```

But when I create a package with the same identical function inside (copy paste!), I get this fault when running the function:

```
"Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'hline_DL' not found"
```

If I take away the rows above, then the rest of the function works well in the package (plotting what I want, but without the dashed horizontal line at `y=22`).

Why is it working as a standalone function, and not in a package? How can I fix it?

Comment: I have import(ggplot2) in the NAMESPACE file (if that is what you mean, I'm new at creating packages).

Comment: Yes, I realize now I think I misunderstood the problem...

Comment: Try moving `yintercept = hline_DL` outside of `aes`, since you're setting it, not mapping it anyway. There's some sort of non-standard evaluation problem happening in `aes()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, my suggestion worked. Namely, put `yintercept = hline_DL` outside of `aes()`, to avoid the non-standard evaluation taking place.

In general, aesthetics that are set to a single value should not be set inside `aes()` anyway.

Comment: any idea to thisstange aes behavior? is the scope change when we put the function in a package?

Comment: @agstudy I think I'd call this strange user behavior, not strange `aes()` behavior. Regardless, I consider getting names to evaluate properly within multiple nested functions witchcraft anyway.

Comment: you're right I am asking just to understand R behavior , I'll test with aes_string anyway.